# How do I import custom made bootstrap.zip file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to change the size of the @grid-float-breakpoint attribute and I did by creating a custom bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
I now need to know how to import the .zip it gives me. Do I have to import every file individually?

Comment: import what?  You need to include all three folders on the server, but then it's just a matter of linking to the minified CSS and JS files

Answer (score 0):

It depens on what you need and how you are including your files... but in general, yes, you need to include all the files yourself.

If you just want to use css feature (grid) you have to include the bootstrap.css. If you need things like modal, popover or tooltip you will also need to include the bootstrap.js file.

The fonts are used from within the css declarations. So you don´t need to include them but they should be laying somewhere as an asset.